# how to create an xml using objective-C with respect to data storage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, core-data

I want to save user generated data in an XML file in the iphone. While we have NSXMLParser to parse through any xml from a url, do we have any method to create a xml file which can be stored in the app documents directory, so that i can use the parser to read the file and then display the contents back in the app.

Or using Core Data is the last resort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `libxml2` and, specifically, `xmlTextWriter`. Lots of examples available through Google.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds: that was pretty useful,thanks. just one confirmation though, I just need to import this framework into my project using Add Framework, correct?

Comment: Take a look at http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html for some setup tips.

Answer (score 1):

Look into NSCoder & NSKeyedArchiver.  for example with NSDictionary, you can do:

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

it'll write out the data as a plist.  plists are in XML format.